# Aborting an ongoing Firebase database request

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering if there is any way to cancel/abort a Firebase Realtime Database request when it hasn't returned any results yet.

Consider the following:

1) User selects an item from a list
2) (Web) app makes a request to retrieve some messages or other data for that item
3) The user navigates back and selects a different item
4) The Firebase request returns with results for the wrong item

A regular xhr request can be aborted. A timeout (setTimeout) can be cleared. Is there any way to abort/cancel an ongoing firebase request?

Example:

```
var request;
// ..

if (request) { abort(request); request = null; }
request = firebase.database().ref("item1/").once("value", callback);
```

PS: this question is about the database but I guess this would be really handy for most firebase services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to abort a read operation.

If you don't want you app to use the data anymore, you can detach the listener by calling `off()`.

This doesn't just work for listeners you register using .on() but also works for .once().

Example:

```
firebase.db.ref("/item1").once("value", function(snap) { console.log("1: ", snap.val()); });
firebase.db.ref("/item1").off();
firebase.db.ref("/item2").once("value", function(snap) { console.log("2: ", snap.val()); });
```

Prints the following in the console:

> 2:  { ... }

In other words: the callback from the first line never gets called (unless it returns a result before .off() is called)

Comment: But I don't have a listener in this case. I use "once". Could I do ref("item1/").once(), then ref("item1/").off and then ref("item2/").once()? would that never fire the callback for item1?

Comment: Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Wow. That seems to work! So instead of storing an 'id' and aborting that I can use the ref. I'll add an answer to this question in a moment. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure why you'd add a second answer with what I told you. If you want the answer to contain a sample, propose an edit.

Comment: Good point. Just did so and will remove my own answer :) Thanks again!